# Changing font-family on JS : can't set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, undefined, font-family

I seem to have a problem when trying to change font on click of a button with JS. Here is the function:

```
    var fontFamily = 'papyrus'
function changeFont(fontFamily){
    document.getElementsByClassName(".forma, .descrip").style.fontFamily 
        };
```

Here is my html line for the button that I use:

```
<input type="button" value="Mode Psychédélique" 
       onclick="chBackcolor('magenta'), changeColor('blue'), 
       changeHeadingColor('green'), changefont('papyrus')">      `
```

I get the error "Cannot set property of undefined", but I don't understand why since I put the variable.
Any thoughts?

BIG EDIT (sorry for that, former commenters)

Comment: `oDomElement.style.fontFamily = papyrus` i see a type here

Comment: What is `oDomElement` ?

Comment: Oh yes sorry @CodeManiac I see what you mean. I corrected it but still nothing

Comment: Do the other 3 methods work for you (those which change color)? If you changed `oDomElement` to `ele` and your code still doesn't work, please edit your post accordingly. Why you calc `matches` and don't use it? More importantly, have you tried changing font for `h2` – the elements for which you changed color successfully?

Comment: The ones that change the color work actually, I edited my code for you to see where I am at, still no changes on visual. And no I didn't try changing font for h2, since I already changed color for p and that this is what I'm aiming at ! ^^

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems like in your code

```
ele.style.fontFamily = papyrus
```

1. No argument for papyrus

Unless you forgot to add "" quotes, there is no declared variable for papyrus

2. Add type of font

This includes cursive, sans-serif, etc.
 Try using this link if it helps: [W3Schools fontFamily JS attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontfamily.asp)

Comment: You should avoid to like against w3school, they used to have many errors and inaccuracies. While they got better after many complains they still have many flaws and incomplete informations [mdn font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) is a more complete reference.